# PHp Facebook application - good session / cache solution?

Tags: php, session, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a facebook application with PHP SDK (and severals php pages) and I want a good system a session.

Do you know a good system of session/cache?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The facebook PHP SDK uses sessions by default if your using the latest version of it.

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk